# How to prevent json from converting float into int?

Tags: json, parsing, google-chrome

I'm writing a script that loads the Chrome Preferences file (JSON object), modify and save it back (easily set my prefs on various machines). 
I use JSON.parse to read the file and JSON.stringify to create the string that I write back.

Chrome refuses to read my saved file, when I run a file compare I can see that some values were converted automatically from float to int:

"someval": 1.0,
to
 
"someval": 1,

Is there a way to prevent this automatic conversion? 
I'm using json2.min.js and when I tried to use json3.min.js I still get an int after parsing and an error when calling JSON.stringify.

Thank you,

Comment: Having a similar problem. Did you resolve this issue.

Comment: Same here, did someone find it? It works for 0.5 which stays float, but 1.0 will convert to 1